# Mysql replace file extension stored in database

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, database, wordpress

Am working with a wordpress site, that use to have a lot heavy of png files on the uploads folder, (wp-content/uploads/year/month/filenames.png)

To reduce the disk usage on server I changed all the files to be .jpg, but, there are still a lot of references in the database (on the wp-post table in the guid column) pointing to the old .png files.

I would like to know if there is a way in mysql to **find and replace** all the text ".png" for ".jpg" in the column guid, **but, only for those records that contains "wp-content/uploads/"** (that would mean that am changing only the references to the files I changed and no others like maybe on wordpress themes)

Any solution is welcome, CLI commands, sql commands....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an SQL query in adminer or phpmyadmin. But try [Search RegEx](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-regex/), a good plugin to be able to search and replace (optionally with grep) through all posts, pages, excerpts, comments, titles and meta.

You can find and replace only in post/page content, do a trial run without replacing to see what is being replaced, and more. Your images are in post/page content, not in the GUID column.